# How to play games in numeric order in Freecell?

Tags: gaming

I love to play freecell - I have been playing games in order for years and am up to game 6889. I seem to have had an upgrade!

In the past - when I complete one game - I would automatically go to the next game up - (numerically)

Now when I click on "want to play again" I get a random game - not the next game in the number sequence.

To continue in playing the number sequence - I have to go to "select game" and I can choose the game I want - but the game that came up randomly - is counted as a loss. 
How do I get back to being able to play games in number order?

Comment: Welcome to SU, please take the time to read the [help](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on how to use the site.  SuperUser "is not about …  •video games or consoles"

Comment: Try at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about gaming, better suited for http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You will still have to select your game number manually, but rather than clicking "want to play again" at the end of the game, you need to click the option that leaves you in the current game and then choose "select game" - this way, you didn't start and abandon a new game and this doesn't count as a loss.

There is no automated process to doing this in the default version that ships with Windows.